# Why can't HashMap have different NaN values as keys?

Tags: java, data-structures, hashmap

```
import java.util.*;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      Map<Float, Integer> m = new HashMap<>();
      
      m.put(Float.intBitsToFloat(0x7f800001), 1);
      m.put(Float.intBitsToFloat(0x7f800002), 2);
      
      System.out.println(m.size());
    }
}
```

Why does the above code return `1` as the size of `m`? `0x7f800001` and `0x7f800002` are both NaN float values, but since `NaN != NaN` by definition, this should not cause a collision.

The behavior is similar to the documented handling of `null` keys in the Java Hashmap, but I can't find anything that indicates that `NaN` is handled as `null` by HashMap.

Comment: Think about it: if `NaN != NaN`, how would you find the correct key?

Comment: By iterating over the map. In my case I only need to write all the values to a file after populating the map. But yes, it would break some of the basic map functions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Float.equals(Object)` is documented as:

> Compares this object against the specified object. The result is true if and only if the argument is not null and is a `Float` object that represents a float with the same value as the float represented by this object. For this purpose, two float values are considered to be the same if and only if the method `floatToIntBits(float)`  returns the identical `int` value when applied to each.

Now that *sounds* like different NaN values should be treated as non-equal, but `floatToIntBits` documentation includes (emphasis mine):

> If the argument is NaN, the result is 0x7fc00000.
>
> In all cases, the result is an integer that, when given to the `intBitsToFloat(int)` method, will produce a floating-point value the same as the argument to `floatToIntBits` **(except all NaN values are collapsed to a single "canonical" NaN value)**.

So basically, `Float.equals` (and `Float.hashCode`, which also uses `floatToIntBits(float)`) treats all NaN values as equal.